# Will a gtx 760 4GB work in a alienware X51 with the 330 watt psu?

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade

I have a alienware X51 with the specs of:

PSU: 330W 
CPU: I5 3450 3.1GHZ 
RAM: 8GB 1600MHZ 
GPU: GT 640 1GB GDDR5 
HDD: 1TB 7200 RPM

I just want a plain and simple answer and to know if it won't work, what will. I should also add that i do have two 6-pin power cables inside.

Comment: Related: [What happens if a video card cannot get enough power?](http://superuser.com/questions/468375/what-happens-if-a-video-card-cannot-get-enough-power)

Comment: Sadly the answer is straight up no. It's also almost impossible to upgrade your power supply to support such a card. Basically you are stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: no.

Nvidia recommends a 500 watts PSU ([source](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-760/specifications)), and say the card itself will take up to 170 watts alone. In comparison, your card is rated at [49 watts](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt640/specifications).

330 watts leaves very little for the rest of the system once you substract the video card. Consider that a CPU alone ca eat nearly 100 watts (your i5 is rated at 77 watts), so 330 will most assuredly won't deliver. It might boot, but will fail or cause crashes as soon as you load a game.

What will work? A 500+ watts PSU.

Comment: the x51 uses a laptop style power supply - and apparently the biggest stock one is 330W - and that seems to be the r2. I'm missing something here. There do seem to be versions of the R2 that come with the 760, so it may be possible. Kinda curious, really  http://alienware-x51.wikia.com/wiki/Alienware_x51_Wiki  and http://www.legitreviews.com/alienware-x51-r2-review_125229 for sources

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks, I stand corrected and edited my answer.